# How to call multiple APIs using loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hi I'm making SPA react program
I have some question

I want to know how can I use this JSON data HackNews

```
const [storyIds, setStoryIds] = useState([]);
  const list = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    Top_API().then((res) => {
      this.res = res.data.slice(0, 3);
      this.res.forEach((ele) => {
        axios
          .get("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + ele + ".json")
          .then((res) => {
            list.push({
              id: res.data.id,
              title: res.data.title,
              url: res.data.url,
              user: res.data.by,
              score: res.data.score
            });
            setStoryIds(list);
          });
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

this is my code i want to print this api data
I print JSON data like this

```
{JSON.stringify(storyIds[0])}
```

This code works well. However, from the storyIds[1] arrangement, it is not visible on the screen. I checked that it was output from the console.

And when I go to a different page,
If I output the contents of my code array, an error occurs that the array cannot be found when you return to the page.
ex)

```
{JSON.stringify(storyIds[0].title)}
```

If you write like the code above, an error occurs that the array is not defined.

I've been trying to solve this situation for three days now without a proper solution.

The code that you print on the screen is as follows.

```
<div className="n1">
          
          <a href={JSON.stringify(storyIds[0])}>
            {JSON.stringify(storyIds[0])}
          </a>
          <br />
          by: {JSON.stringify(storyIds[0])}
        </div>
        <div className="n2">{JSON.stringify(storyIds[1])}</div>
        <div className="n3">{JSON.stringify(storyIds[2])}</div>
      </div>
```

the data look's like

```
[{"id":30186326,"title":"Facebook loses users for the first time","url":"https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2022/02/02/facebook-earnings-meta/","user":"prostoalex","score":994},{"id":30186894,"title":"In second largest DeFi hack, Blockchain Bridge loses $320M Ether","url":"https://blockworks.co/in-second-largest-defi-hack-ever-blockchain-bridge-loses-320m-ether/","user":"CharlesW","score":400}]
```

**how can I print this API response my screen?**

Comment: Try using  `async await` as the loop is not waiting for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `async await` with `Promise.all` for waiting for response from API

```
useEffect(() => {
    Top_API().then(async (res) => {
      this.res = res.data.slice(0, 5);
      Promise.all(
        this.res.map(async (r) => {
          return await axios.get(
            "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + r + ".json"
          );
        })
      ).then((resolved) => {
        resolved.map((resolve) => {
          list.push({
            id: resolve.data.id,
            title: resolve.data.title,
            url: resolve.data.url,
            user: resolve.data.by,
            score: resolve.data.score
          });
        });
        setStoryIds(list);
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: I tried it the way you told me, but there was no change in the output. Is there any other way?

Comment: I have revised it, try it now!

Comment: It's working but There is still a situation in which things except the first arrangement do not appear on the screen.

Comment: please try with sandbox I will help you out to write code

Comment: i'm using sandbox this project this is my sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/hacknewsapi-iomdr?file=/src/show/Top.jsx

Comment: Three pieces of data must be displayed on the screen. how can i ??

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hacknewsapi-forked-s6btz?file=/src/showApi/HomeApi.jsx
Resolved